# Возникла проблема с просмотром и парсингом html

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Проблема заключается в том что при просмотре кода элемента высвечивается полный код страницы. Вот как выглядит определённый класс: 
[image: Через просмотр кода элемента]

А вот как выглядит этот же класс через просмотр полного кода страницы:
[image: Через просмотр полного кода страницы]

При попытке прасинга так же в классе нет абсолютно ничего.
Как можно решить данную проблему и возможно ли?
Вот мой код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://edu.mes.ru/psychologistmentor/default/student-success"
headers = {
    "Accept": "text/css,*/*;q=0.1",
    "Accept-Encodig": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Cookie": "SID=19ae3d9e6d9bc18cd6079979839a8ac4; _csrf=10395df0d99982d50d20cda7b1af2ccd2e36dced27470c5f0445ba10ec8a0df6a%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A5%3A%22_csrf%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A32%3A%22s8v9jWwOcatOgdRdfMkhUocCpHTRJ67e%22%3B%7D; _identity=476c25038da40d702f037e15e78081823d4bde7696ad356284302b204b5df53fa%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A9%3A%22_identity%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A50%3A%22%5B3989%2C%22Dlx8nRoFbRXzD7_l1W6SGv7CO2Ui1pb7%22%2C25920000%5D%22%3B%7D",
    "DNT": "1",
    "Host": "edu.mes.ru",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0"
}


def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
    return r


def get_content(html):
    soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
    result = soup.find('div', class_='gantt')
    print(result) # Вывод: <div class="gantt"></div>




def parse():
    html = get_html(url)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        get_content(html.text)
    else:
        print("ERROR" + str(html.status_code))

parse()
```

Answer (score 0):

Мое видение данной проблемы заключается в следующем:

Вы можете попробовать сделать парсер с другим классом.

а) если получится, значит вы берете не тот класс.

б) если не получится, посмотрите библиотеку selenium, возможно ваша страница отдает js код

Comment: Я могу взять любой класс, кроме тех, что находятся внутри класса «gantt”, а именно его содержимое мне и нужно.